# Java Jersey: Get client IP in rest method on Tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat, post, ip, jersey

I have a Jersey rest webservice that runs on tomcat 6. I have a @Post method that consumes Multipart:

```
@Path("identify")   
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String identifyReception(com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart multiPart) throws Exception {
```

I would like to get the client IP address inside this method. I found out that you can use @Context HttpServletRequest inside Get method. But in post method I need the multipart input argument. I have also found out that tomcat does not support Servlet specification...

Is there another way I can do it?

Comment: I don't see a direct way in the api, but have you tried getHeaders(). ie. multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0).getHeaders(); then search through the list of headers for the IP/Host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found out that you can use @Context HttpServletRequest inside Get method. But in post method I need the multipart input argument.

I don't think the two are mutually exclusive. Let your method take two arguments (I don't think it matters what order they're in) and annotate one of them with `@Context`. I believe that will work whether it's a get, post, whatever. You could also just annotate a field with `@Context` and Jersey will initialize it for you before it calls your @GET method.

Comment: I tried this out on my own during the weekend before I saw your asnwer and I think this actually works but I need more testing. But Thanks :>

Comment: I tried to use `@Context HttpServletRequest inside Get` method but get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Context to Annotation` error. Why?